# Upload multipart entitty ro android to ASP classic server

Tags: android, asp-classic

there
I try to make Android App that uploade foto to my server
currently my server using old clasic ASP, im using Scrip from FreeASPUpload all foto is upladed to server but in corrupted format, the android code is work fine when uploaded to php server (i found it in adroidhive.net) i know something wrong about payload here but jus cant figure it out how to solve this problem, please help me guys,
asp script :

```
    <%
const DEFAULT_ASP_CHUNK_SIZE = 200000
const adModeReadWrite = 3
const adTypeBinary = 1
const adTypeText = 2
const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
uploadsDirVar = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\newupload\tmp\" 

call  SaveFiles()

function SaveFiles
    Dim Upload, fileName, fileSize, ks, i, fileKey

    Set Upload = New FreeASPUpload
    Upload.Save(uploadsDirVar)


    If Err.Number<>0 then Exit function

    SaveFiles = ""
    ks = Upload.UploadedFiles.keys
    if (UBound(ks) <> -1) then

        for each fileKey in Upload.UploadedFiles.keys
      response.Write SaveFiles & Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).FileName & " (" & Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).Length & "B) "
        next
    else

    end if
    if Ubound(ks)<>-1 then
    %>

    <%
    end if  

    end function


Class FreeASPUpload
    Public UploadedFiles
    Public FormElements

    Private VarArrayBinRequest
    Private StreamRequest
    Private uploadedYet
    Private internalChunkSize

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        Set UploadedFiles = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Set FormElements = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Set StreamRequest = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        StreamRequest.Type = adTypeText
        StreamRequest.Open
        uploadedYet = false
        internalChunkSize = DEFAULT_ASP_CHUNK_SIZE
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()
        If IsObject(UploadedFiles) Then
            UploadedFiles.RemoveAll()
            Set UploadedFiles = Nothing
        End If
        If IsObject(FormElements) Then
            FormElements.RemoveAll()
            Set FormElements = Nothing
        End If
        StreamRequest.Close
        Set StreamRequest = Nothing
    End Sub

    Public Property Get Form(sIndex)
        Form = ""
        If FormElements.Exists(LCase(sIndex)) Then Form = FormElements.Item(LCase(sIndex))
    End Property

    Public Property Get Files()
        Files = UploadedFiles.Items
    End Property

    Public Property Get Exists(sIndex)
            Exists = false
            If FormElements.Exists(LCase(sIndex)) Then Exists = true
    End Property

    Public Property Get FileExists(sIndex)
        FileExists = false
            if UploadedFiles.Exists(LCase(sIndex)) then FileExists = true
    End Property

    Public Property Get chunkSize()
        chunkSize = internalChunkSize
    End Property

    Public Property Let chunkSize(sz)
        internalChunkSize = sz
    End Property


    Public Sub Save(path)
        Dim streamFile, fileItem, filePath

        if Right(path, 1) <> "\" then path = path & "\"

        if not uploadedYet then Upload

        For Each fileItem In UploadedFiles.Items
            filePath = path & fileItem.FileName
            Set streamFile = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            streamFile.Type = adTypeBinary
            streamFile.Open
            StreamRequest.Position=fileItem.Start
            StreamRequest.CopyTo streamFile, fileItem.Length
            streamFile.SaveToFile filePath, adSaveCreateOverWrite
            streamFile.close
            Set streamFile = Nothing
            fileItem.Path = filePath
         Next
    End Sub

    public sub SaveOne(path, num, byref outFileName, byref outLocalFileName)
        Dim streamFile, fileItems, fileItem, fs

        set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        if Right(path, 1) <> "\" then path = path & "\"

        if not uploadedYet then Upload
        if UploadedFiles.Count > 0 then
            fileItems = UploadedFiles.Items
            set fileItem = fileItems(num)

            outFileName = fileItem.FileName
            outLocalFileName = GetFileName(path, outFileName)

            Set streamFile = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            streamFile.Type = adTypeBinary
            streamFile.Open
            StreamRequest.Position = fileItem.Start
            StreamRequest.CopyTo streamFile, fileItem.Length
            streamFile.SaveToFile path & outLocalFileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
            streamFile.close
            Set streamFile = Nothing
            fileItem.Path = path & filename
        end if
    end sub

    Public Function SaveBinRequest(path) ' For debugging purposes
        StreamRequest.SaveToFile path & "\debugStream.bin", 2
    End Function

    Public Sub DumpData() 'only works if files are plain text
        Dim i, aKeys, f
        response.write "Form Items:<br>"
        aKeys = FormElements.Keys
        For i = 0 To FormElements.Count -1 ' Iterate the array
            response.write aKeys(i) & " = " & FormElements.Item(aKeys(i)) & "<BR>"
        Next
        response.write "Uploaded Files:<br>"
        For Each f In UploadedFiles.Items
            response.write "Name: " & f.FileName & "<br>"
            response.write "Type: " & f.ContentType & "<br>"
            response.write "Start: " & f.Start & "<br>"
            response.write "Size: " & f.Length & "<br>"
         Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub Upload()
        Dim nCurPos, nDataBoundPos, nLastSepPos
        Dim nPosFile, nPosBound
        Dim sFieldName, osPathSep, auxStr
        Dim readBytes, readLoop, tmpBinRequest

        'RFC1867 Tokens
        Dim vDataSep
        Dim tNewLine, tDoubleQuotes, tTerm, tFilename, tName, tContentDisp, tContentType
        tNewLine = String2Byte(Chr(13))
        tDoubleQuotes = String2Byte(Chr(34))
        tTerm = String2Byte("--")
        tFilename = String2Byte("filename=""")
        tName = String2Byte("name=""")
        tContentDisp = String2Byte("Content-Disposition")
        tContentType = String2Byte("Content-Type:")

        uploadedYet = true

        on error resume next
            ' Copy binary request to a byte array, on which functions like InstrB and others can be used to search for separation tokens
            readBytes = internalChunkSize
            VarArrayBinRequest = Request.BinaryRead(readBytes)
            VarArrayBinRequest = midb(VarArrayBinRequest, 1, lenb(VarArrayBinRequest))
            Do Until readBytes < 1
                tmpBinRequest = Request.BinaryRead(readBytes)
                if readBytes > 0 then
                    VarArrayBinRequest = VarArrayBinRequest & midb(tmpBinRequest, 1, lenb(tmpBinRequest))
                end if
            Loop
            StreamRequest.WriteText(VarArrayBinRequest)
            StreamRequest.Flush()
            if Err.Number <> 0 then 
                response.write "<br><br><B>System reported this error:</B><p>"
                response.write Err.Description & "<p>"
                response.write "The most likely cause for this error is the incorrect setup of AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed in IIS MetaBase. Please see instructions in the <A HREF='http://www.freeaspupload.net/freeaspupload/requirements.asp'>requirements page of freeaspupload.net</A>.<p>"
                Exit Sub
            end if
        on error goto 0 'reset error handling

        nCurPos = FindToken(tNewLine,1) 'Note: nCurPos is 1-based (and so is InstrB, MidB, etc)

        If nCurPos <= 1  Then Exit Sub


        vDataSep = MidB(VarArrayBinRequest, 1, nCurPos-1)


        nDataBoundPos = 1


        nLastSepPos = FindToken(vDataSep & tTerm, 1)

        Do Until nDataBoundPos = nLastSepPos

            nCurPos = SkipToken(tContentDisp, nDataBoundPos)
            nCurPos = SkipToken(tName, nCurPos)
            sFieldName = ExtractField(tDoubleQuotes, nCurPos)

            nPosFile = FindToken(tFilename, nCurPos)
            nPosBound = FindToken(vDataSep, nCurPos)

            If nPosFile <> 0 And  nPosFile < nPosBound Then
                Dim oUploadFile
                Set oUploadFile = New UploadedFile

                nCurPos = SkipToken(tFilename, nCurPos)
                auxStr = ExtractField(tDoubleQuotes, nCurPos)
                osPathSep = "\"
                if InStr(auxStr, osPathSep) = 0 then osPathSep = "/"
                oUploadFile.FileName = Right(auxStr, Len(auxStr)-InStrRev(auxStr, osPathSep))

                if (Len(oUploadFile.FileName) > 0) then 'File field not left empty
                    nCurPos = SkipToken(tContentType, nCurPos)

                    auxStr = ExtractField(tNewLine, nCurPos)
                    oUploadFile.ContentType = Right(auxStr, Len(auxStr)-InStrRev(auxStr, " "))
                    nCurPos = FindToken(tNewLine, nCurPos) + 4 'skip empty line

                    oUploadFile.Start = nCurPos+1
                    oUploadFile.Length = FindToken(vDataSep, nCurPos) - 2 - nCurPos

                    If oUploadFile.Length > 0 Then UploadedFiles.Add LCase(sFieldName), oUploadFile
                End If
            Else
                Dim nEndOfData, fieldValueUniStr
                nCurPos = FindToken(tNewLine, nCurPos) + 4 'skip empty line
                nEndOfData = FindToken(vDataSep, nCurPos) - 2
                fieldValueuniStr = ConvertUtf8BytesToString(nCurPos, nEndOfData-nCurPos)
                If Not FormElements.Exists(LCase(sFieldName)) Then 
                    FormElements.Add LCase(sFieldName), fieldValueuniStr
                else
                    FormElements.Item(LCase(sFieldName))= FormElements.Item(LCase(sFieldName)) & ", " & fieldValueuniStr
                end if 

            End If

            'Advance to next separator
            nDataBoundPos = FindToken(vDataSep, nCurPos)
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Function SkipToken(sToken, nStart)
        SkipToken = InstrB(nStart, VarArrayBinRequest, sToken)
        If SkipToken = 0 then
            Response.write "Error in parsing uploaded binary request. The most likely cause for this error is the incorrect setup of AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed in IIS MetaBase. Please see instructions in the <A HREF='http://www.freeaspupload.net/freeaspupload/requirements.asp'>requirements page of freeaspupload.net</A>.<p>"
            Response.End
        end if
        SkipToken = SkipToken + LenB(sToken)
    End Function

    Private Function FindToken(sToken, nStart)
        FindToken = InstrB(nStart, VarArrayBinRequest, sToken)
    End Function

    Private Function ExtractField(sToken, nStart)
        Dim nEnd
        nEnd = InstrB(nStart, VarArrayBinRequest, sToken)
        If nEnd = 0 then
            Response.write "Error in parsing uploaded binary request."
            Response.End
        end if
        ExtractField = ConvertUtf8BytesToString(nStart, nEnd-nStart)
    End Function

    'String to byte string conversion
    Private Function String2Byte(sString)
        Dim i
        For i = 1 to Len(sString)
           String2Byte = String2Byte & ChrB(AscB(Mid(sString,i,1)))
        Next
    End Function

    Private Function ConvertUtf8BytesToString(start, length)    
        StreamRequest.Position = 0

        Dim objStream
        Dim strTmp

        ' init stream
        Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        objStream.Charset = "utf-8"
        objStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
        objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
        objStream.Open

        ' write bytes into stream
        StreamRequest.Position = start+1
        StreamRequest.CopyTo objStream, length
        objStream.Flush

        ' rewind stream and read text
        objStream.Position = 0
        objStream.Type = adTypeText
        strTmp = objStream.ReadText

        ' close up and return
        objStream.Close
        Set objStream = Nothing
        ConvertUtf8BytesToString = strTmp   
    End Function
End Class

Class UploadedFile
    Public ContentType
    Public Start
    Public Length
    Public Path
    Private nameOfFile


    Public Property Let FileName(fN)
        nameOfFile = fN
        nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, "\", "_")
        nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, "/", "_")
        nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, ":", "_")
        nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, "*", "_")
        nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, "?", "_")
        nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, """", "_")
        nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, "<", "_")
        nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, ">", "_")
        nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, "|", "_")
    End Property

    Public Property Get FileName()
        FileName = nameOfFile
    End Property


End Class


Function SubstNoReg(initialStr, oldStr, newStr)
    Dim currentPos, oldStrPos, skip
    If IsNull(initialStr) Or Len(initialStr) = 0 Then
        SubstNoReg = ""
    ElseIf IsNull(oldStr) Or Len(oldStr) = 0 Then
        SubstNoReg = initialStr
    Else
        If IsNull(newStr) Then newStr = ""
        currentPos = 1
        oldStrPos = 0
        SubstNoReg = ""
        skip = Len(oldStr)
        Do While currentPos <= Len(initialStr)
            oldStrPos = InStr(currentPos, initialStr, oldStr)
            If oldStrPos = 0 Then
                SubstNoReg = SubstNoReg & Mid(initialStr, currentPos, Len(initialStr) - currentPos + 1)
                currentPos = Len(initialStr) + 1
            Else
                SubstNoReg = SubstNoReg & Mid(initialStr, currentPos, oldStrPos - currentPos) & newStr
                currentPos = oldStrPos + skip
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Function

Function GetFileName(strSaveToPath, FileName)
    Dim Counter
    Dim Flag
    Dim strTempFileName
    Dim FileExt
    Dim NewFullPath
    dim objFSO, p
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Counter = 0
    p = instrrev(FileName, ".")
    FileExt = mid(FileName, p+1)
    strTempFileName = left(FileName, p-1)
    NewFullPath = strSaveToPath & "\" & FileName
    Flag = False

    Do Until Flag = True
        If objFSO.FileExists(NewFullPath) = False Then
            Flag = True
            GetFileName = Mid(NewFullPath, InstrRev(NewFullPath, "\") + 1)
        Else
            Counter = Counter + 1
            NewFullPath = strSaveToPath & "\" & strTempFileName & Counter & "." & FileExt
        End If
    Loop
End Function 

%>
```

and AndroidmultipartEntity.java

```
import java.io.FilterOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class AndroidMultiPartEntity extends MultipartEntity

{

    private final ProgressListener listener;

    public AndroidMultiPartEntity(final ProgressListener listener) {
        super();
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public AndroidMultiPartEntity(final HttpMultipartMode mode,
                                  final ProgressListener listener) {
        super(mode);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public AndroidMultiPartEntity(HttpMultipartMode mode, final String boundary,
                                  final Charset charset, final ProgressListener listener) {
        super(mode, boundary, charset);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
        super.writeTo(new CountingOutputStream(outstream, this.listener));
    }

    public static interface ProgressListener {
        void transferred(long num);
    }

    public static class CountingOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {

        private final ProgressListener listener;
        private long transferred;

        public CountingOutputStream(final OutputStream out,
                                    final ProgressListener listener) {
            super(out);
            this.listener = listener;
            this.transferred = 0;
        }

        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            out.write(b, off, len);
            this.transferred += len;
            this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
        }

        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            out.write(b);
            this.transferred++;
            this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
        }
    }
}
```

Uploadactivity.java

```
import tmg.uploadlagi.AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class UploadActivity extends Activity {
    // LogCat tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private String filePath = null;
    private TextView txtPercentage;
    private ImageView imgPreview;
    private VideoView vidPreview;
    private Button btnUpload;
    long totalSize = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
        txtPercentage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPercentage);
        btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
        vidPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);

        // Changing action bar background color


        // Receiving the data from previous activity
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // image or video path that is captured in previous activity
        filePath = i.getStringExtra("filePath");

        // boolean flag to identify the media type, image or video
        boolean isImage = i.getBooleanExtra("isImage", true);

        if (filePath != null) {
            // Displaying the image or video on the screen
            previewMedia(isImage);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry, file path is missing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // uploading the file to server
                new UploadFileToServer().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Displaying captured image/video on the screen
     * */
    private void previewMedia(boolean isImage) {
        // Checking whether captured media is image or video
        if (isImage) {
            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vidPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            // images
            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

            imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {
            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            vidPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vidPreview.setVideoPath(filePath);
            // start playing
            vidPreview.start();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Uploading the file to server
     * */
    private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // setting progress bar to zero
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // Making progress bar visible
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // updating progress bar value
            progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);

            // updating percentage value
            txtPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return uploadFile();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private String uploadFile() {
            String responseString = null;

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);

            try {
                AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                        new ProgressListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void transferred(long num) {
                                publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                            }
                        });

                File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

                // Adding file data to http body
                entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));

                totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
                httppost.setEntity(entity);

                // Making server call
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    // Server response
                    responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
                } else {
                    responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                            + statusCode;
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            }

            return responseString;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);

            // showing the server response in an alert dialog
            showAlert(result);

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Method to show alert dialog
     * */
    private void showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setTitle("Response from Servers")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: `corrupted format,` means what? Is the whole file uploaded or only a part?

Comment: from the size of the  file i can tell not all file was uploaded, and the file can't be opened in the server (the file are JPG)

Comment: I tried the asp code you provided with a simple html page with an input type="file" and it is working fine. You say it worked with a php page too. I am anot familiar with android, are you setting the enctype as `multipart/form-data` in your android code? It is needed for for ASP to process it correctly.

Comment: yes its work fine with html form or asp form too,the problem is i try to upload form android and get error :(